# HTML center works on server but not on local machine

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour on my local machine, when I access a page on my test server everything is centered like I want. When I run the code on my local machine everything is left aligned, the centering is ignored.

The HTML is really simple so I don't see why this issue has suddenly started to happen.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
       <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="" ID="hlPhoto" runat="server"><asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format( "../images/mugshots/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Photo") )%>' /></asp:HyperLink>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td valign="bottom" align="center">
     <div>
     <b>
      <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"><%# Eval("FullName")%></asp:Label></b>                 </div>
    <div>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Jobtitle")%></asp:Label></div>
    <div>
         <br />
        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="" ID="hlDetail" runat="server"><font size="2">Details</font></asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
    <div>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="userID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Jobtitle")%>' />
    </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: are you using the same browser? same version?

Comment: Yeah using my local browser to open the server page works fine but when I go to local address using same browser everything is left aligned. Very weird.

Comment: Compatibility view sorted out my issue for now

Comment: You might want to know that `valign` and `align` are obsolete: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html. Also, you might want to re-consider using a table for layout.